# reading variables to ps ax script

Tags: bash, ps

Hi I've been searching on the forum but I cant seem to get this right. I am trying to create a script  that asks the user which process they are searching for then returns with a 1 if the process is running.

This works:

```
#!/bin/bash
SERVICE='httpd'
if ps ax | grep -v grep | grep $SERVICE > /dev/null
then
echo "$SERVICE service running, everything is fine"
else
echo "$SERVICE is not running"
fi
```

I want to add this to the script:

```
 echo -e "please enter process name: \c"
 read word
```

for something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo -e "please enter process name: \c"
read input_variable
if ps ax | grep -v grep | grep $varname > /dev/null
then
echo "$SERVICE service running, everything is fine"
else
echo "$SERVICE is not running"
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pgrep`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep) to search for processes:

```
read process_name
if pgrep "${process_name}" >/dev/null 2>&1 ; then
    "echo ${process_name} found"
else
    "echo ${process_name} not found"
fi
```

Comment: Cool thanks got it to go with out the " " on lines 5 and 7